ReactJS Components not showing any output
I am learning React and am stuck with the problem that the components I make, their functions don't show any output, though there's no error message but still I get a blank screen. But when I try to return plain text in app.js, it works fine. Here's my code:
**Index.js **
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';

import App from './App';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
);

App.js
import home from "./pages/home/home";

function App() {
  return (<home/>)
}

export default App;

Home.js (Component)
import home from "./pages/home/home";

function App() {
  return (<home/>)
}

export default App;

Kindly help me in resolving the issue
I tried to change the export by writing it with the function itself, re-run the project, reload the site a few times, but still no output.

In React, the component names always start with a capital Letter. If its all lowercase, like <home/> in your case, it will be treated as semantic HTML element and there's no element called home in html. Change it as follows
import Home from "./pages/home/home";

function App() {
  return <Home/>
}

export default App;


import Home from "./pages/home/home";

function App() {
  return(<Home/>)
}

export default App;


Welcome to StackOverflow. Please improve this answer with a description of the code you posted and how it will help with the issue.

When React components are not displaying any output, there could be several reasons for this issue. Here are some common troubleshooting steps to help resolve the problem:
Check for Errors
Open your browser's developer tools (usually by pressing F12 or right-clicking and selecting "Inspect"), and go to the Console tab. Look for any error messages that might indicate what's going wrong. Fixing errors is crucial as they can prevent components from rendering.
